# Error when trying to add created method in Vue component

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5

**Component**

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="chat-log">
        <chat-message v-for="message in messages" :message="message"></chat-message>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ["messages"]
    }

</script>

<style lang="css">
    .chat-log .chat-message:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    .chat-log {
        overflow-y: auto;
        max-height: 400px;
    }

</style>
```

**When I change the above script code to below. I get errors..**

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ["messages"]
    },
    created() {
        $(".chat-log").scrollTop($(".chat-log").prop('scrollHeight'));
    }

</script>
```

**Error Details**

Unexpected token, expected ;

Issue comes only when adding the created method, Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `created` lifecyle method goes within the body of the Vue component itself, not outside. I mean:

```
export default {
    props: ["messages"],
    created() {
        $(".chat-log").scrollTop($(".chat-log").prop('scrollHeight'));
    }
 }
```

**[Vue.js Lifecycle](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/)**

Comment: I was actually looking for a method that executes once the component is fully loaded. but seems like `created()` will not help. can u suggest something?

Comment: @Pankaj try to take a look [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/). I think you'd go with mounted.

Answer (score 1):

Your `created(){}` method should be encapsulated within your `export default {}` block.

In other words, change your code this:

```
export default {

  props: ["messages"],

  created() {
   $(".chat-log").scrollTop($(".chat-log").prop('scrollHeight'));
  }

},
```

Comment: I was actually looking for a method that executes once the component is fully loaded. but seems like `created()` will not help. can u suggest something?

Comment: @Pankaj That is what created does, it will only run once, same as `mounted(){}`

Comment: Check this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram maybe you are looking for beforeCreate()